# 400 Bad Request error when using .net Paymill Wrapper

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, paymill

I'm trying to use the [.net Paymill Wrapper](http://github.com/jcantos/paymillwrappernet)

When trying to add a subscription, I'm getting back a 400 Bad Request.

To illustrate the problem, I [created a branch](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/paymillwrappernet/tree/400badreq) and [changed the Sandbox console app](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/paymillwrappernet/commit/e25f61ff727066b5e1cfddff272e749ed833bbc1) to call the method to test addSubscription

The problem is happening [here](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/paymillwrappernet/blob/339ccd571948293fbbbd58e2e5a69b448f90dc36/PaymillWrapper/Service/AbstractService.cs#L80-L84) where the request is actually posted.

The content posted is: (as an example)

```
client=client_bbe895116de80b6141fd&
offer=offer_32008ddd39954e71ed48&
payment=pay_81ec02206e9b9c587513
```

It appears this hasn't been updated for sometime, and the original author is unresponsive via email or twitter, so I've forked the repo and am trying to fix the error.

Comment: I don't know anything about .NET, but if you could post what is being sent to the API I could try to figure out what is wrong with the request.  With this information you might be able to track down the issue inside of the wrapper.

Comment: Content posted is shown... Beyond this, I can't really help - it's sent over SSL and fiddler isn't playing nice with decrypting what is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your code and found out that you are not creating the offer object correctly.
In your addSubscription method (SandboxConsole project), i found this code snippet

```
        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
        subscription.Client = new Client() { Id = "client_bbe895116de80b6141fd" };
        subscription.Offer = new Offer() { Id = "offer_32008ddd39954e71ed48" };
        subscription.Payment = new Payment() { Id = "pay_81ec02206e9b9c587513" };
```

Offer object should be initialized with parameters like amount, currency, interval. 
Since the offer object doesn't exist, assigning a subscription to it fails, giving you bad request error.

Comment: Not according to your own documentation... https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/introduction/subscriptions/